# Meteor Mongo update Invalid Query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Why on earth is this update failing? This is basic, I've done this many other times.

```js
Meteor.users.update(id, {$set: {lastname: "Archer"}});
```

That query above has even been simplified from what it originally was, and it's still having the same problem. Originally I was compiling the update programatically:

```js
console.log(obj);
console.log(id);
if (obj) collection.update(id, obj);
```

Here is my exact output from those lines:

```
Object {$set: Object}
    $set: Object
        lastname: "Archer"
        __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
main.js?b9104f881abb80f93da518738bf1bfb4cab0b2b6:68

YXeudfnHyKmsGXaEL
main.js?b9104f881abb80f93da518738bf1bfb4cab0b2b6:69

update failed: MongoError: invalid query
debug.js:41
```

The `id` is correct, and if the `obj` has something wrong with it, it'll be news to me!

Now, I'm quite positive this has nothing to do with my `allow` function. In the first tests of this part of my program, I actually *did* get the `update not allowed` (or whatever it is) error, but I modified my `allow` function to take this into account, and that error went away.

Here's my `allow` function. I have a user system where a user can have a student object that "mirrors" it's name information, hence the added complexity. That portion of the function is only engaged in certain circumstances, and it doesn't alter the behavior of the allowance.

```js
Meteor.users.allow({
    update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        var allow = (userId && (doc._id === userId) && _.without(fields, 
                    'firstname', 'lastname', 'student_ids', 'payment_ids', 'phones').length == 0) || Meteor.user().admin;
        if (allow && modifier.$set && (_.contains(fields, 'firstname') || _.contains(fields, 'lastname'))) {
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
            var obj = {};
            if (modifier.$set.firstname) obj.firstname = modifier.$set.firstname;
            if (modifier.$set.lastname) obj.lastname = modifier.$set.lastname;
            if (obj) Students.update({_id: {$in: user.student_ids}, reflectsUser: true}, {$set: obj});
        }
        return allow;
    }
});
```

Comment: is this on the client or the server? and if on the client: are the appropriate `allow`s set on the server? Also, did you verify that `id` is indeed a valid id?

Comment: It's on the client. And yes, I've printed out that `id` and it's correct

Comment: Have you tried using {_id: id} instead of id? Like this: `Meteor.users.update({_id: id}, {$set: {lastname: "Archer"}});`

Comment: @stubailo that's the same in Meteor.

Comment: "Users are by default allowed to specify their own profile field with Accounts.createUser and modify it with Meteor.users.update. To allow users to edit additional fields, use Meteor.users.allow.". Have you done that? and is `id` the userId of the current user?

Comment: Yes I have an `allow` function, I'll post it.

Comment: `id` isn't for the current user, but as you can see my `allow` function checks if the current user is an admin, in which case they can make whatever changes they like (I'll make that more secure in the future)

Comment: I've added more information, more detailed logs of the query object etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my `allow` function *was* the problem, but in a bit of a sneaky way.

The `Meteor.users.update` call wasn't actually the one that was failing, it was this one:

```js
Students.update({_id: {$in: user.student_ids}, reflectsUser: true}, {$set: obj});
```

I wasn't properly checking that `user.student_ids` field, so if it was `undefined` (that user didn't have any students) then the query was invalid. Throwing in a line to vet that array:

```js
var student_ids = user.student_ids || [];
```

solved the problem.

Since the Meteor error didn't tell me which query was invalid, it led me on a bit of a wild goose chase. Just goes to show that good errors can go a long way!

Also, performing database queries that have other database queries as side-effects is something to be done very carefully.